# Country of Dropbox sign in

Tags: dropbox

We have had suspicious activity in one of the Dropbox accounts at my company. We believe it is an ex-coworker signing in and deleting files. We cannot change the password (stupid company policy), but is there a way to obtain the country of where the sign-in occurred? Anything at all that can give us some evidence.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question—please check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.dropbox.com/account/security, you might see info about the location of sign in devices.

If it's a paid business account, you can see more details in the Admin console. See https://help.dropbox.com/account-access/view-activity